# How can I make a call to an SIP address from Google Voice number?

Tags: google-hangouts, google-voice, sip

How can I make a call to an SIP address (e.g. sip:613@fwd.pulver.com) from Google Voice number?
Does Google Hangout support calls to SIP addresses?

Can an SIP address call my Google Voice number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Google voice is no longer accepting SIP traffic. See [here](https://www.onsip.com/blog/google-voice-sip-address-no-longer-available-sipvoicegooglecom-now-silent) for more info.

Comment: Hi, I want to evaluate this answer, but as someone who is uninformed about SIP, could you clarify if SIP calling needs both parties to have SIP addresses? The article mentioned that Google Voice doesn't provide SIP addresses anymore and is no longer accepting SIP traffic, but didn't really say anything if Google Voice can still make a call to other SIP addresses or not. Thanks!